# How to tell which Apache is running

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, homebrew

I just updated to macOS Catalina (10.15.1).

I got me own Apache installed by HomeBrew. This Apache seems not to accept my configuration. I somehow think that Apple reenabled its default Apache and I have no Idea how to tell which one is running?

Comment: What is the Last Value of the Output written by the `ps wwwuxaf|grep -i httpd` Command?

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`, I fixed it by reinstalling the brew version of apache, but it would stil be nice to know how to find the running version

Comment: Can you type `which httpd`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Find used Apache:

```
$ which -a httpd
/usr/local/bin/httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd

$ whereis httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
```

`which` shows you both of your apache, `whereis` shows you the currently used apache

### Internal Apache

- **Binary:** `/usr/sbin/httpd`
- **Start/Stop:** `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start`
- **Version:** `/usr/sbin/apachectl -v`
- **Config:** `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

### Homebrew Apache

- **Binary:** `/usr/local/bin/httpd` (symlink to ../Cellar/httpd)
- **Start/Stop:** `sudo /usr/local/bin/apachectl start`
- **Version:** `/usr/local/bin/apachectl -v`
- **Config:** `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

### Homebrew Apache (Apple Silicon)

substitute `/opt/homebrew` for `/usr/local` in the group directly above. for example

- **Binary:** `/opt/homebrew/bin/httpd` (symlink to ../Cellar/httpd)
- **Start/Stop:** `sudo /opt/homebrew/bin/apachectl start`
- **Version:** `/opt/homebrew/bin/apachectl -v`
- **Config:** `/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

***Note:*** For me the Internal and the Homebrew Apache are at the same Version.

Comment: Nito, this is good information that I have been looking for.  When using "which httpd" I get the /usr/local/bin/httpd BUT when I run "whereis httpd"  I'm getting the /usr/sbin/httpd.  Does this mean I'm currently using the internal apache?  Running both commands with "apachectl" instead of "httpd" gives me the same information.  How would I get my computer to use the brew version instead?  Or is it using it already?  I'm confused about "whereis" giving me the /usr/sbin path.

Comment: In addition, running "apachectl -V" outputs the Homebrew Apache config info and running "apachectl start" seems to start my Homebrew apache.  Why is "whereis apachectl" showing me the internal apache executable directory????

Comment: Which executable is used for a command linke `apachectl` depends on the order in your `$PATH` variable. The shell searches in the folders given in your `$PATH` from beginning to end and stops on the first hit. So `/usr/sbin/` might come before `/usr/local/bin/`. Just `echo $PATH` to check that. You can modify your `$PATH` or include the path in your command as shown in my answer `/usr/local/bin/apachectl -v` or `/usr/local/bin/apachectl stop`

Comment: Nito, my /usr/local/bin directory actually comes before /usr/sbin/ in my path.  When using apachectl -V it DOES show the correct apache (Homebrew apache).  But whereis apachectl outputs the path the Mac apache.  WHY?

Answer (score 1):

Nito's answer is correct.  But `whereis` does not give you the current apache being used.  [This is a better description of what `whereis` does](https://superuser.com/questions/1531217/understanding-whereis-apachectl-output-on-my-mac/1531233#1531233).  I was getting confused, as per the above comments, so I posted another question.  This will help to clarify if others are in my situation.