# Understanding "whereis apachectl" output on my Mac

Tags: apache-http-server, homebrew, macos-mojave

I installed apache using Homebrew on my Mac giving resulting in currently 2 instances of apache on my Mac.  I have disabled the auto loading of the Mac installed instance of Apache.

When I run `which -a apachectl` I get both paths to the apachectl executable: `/usr/sbin/apachectl` and `/usr/local/bin/apachectl` (which is a symlink to the Homebrew installed Apache).  Then when I run `which apachectl` is points me to the Homebrew installed version of Apache.

However, when I run `whereis apachectl` it outputs the path to the Mac installed version of Apache: `/usr/sbin/apachectl`.

In addition when running `apachectl start/stop` I don't need the `sudo` command so it would seem that I am starting/stopping the Homebrew installed instance of Apache.  It also load my webpages correctly from the correct directly, so I'm assuming that Apache is loading the Homebrew installed httpd.conf file.  When I try to run `/usr/sbin/apachectl` the command lines ask for sudo to be used which tells me that the Apache executable in that directory is the Mac installed apache.

Oddly enough, when I run `apachectl -V` it outputs the config info for my Homebrew installed Apache.

Why is `whereis apachectl` pointing to `/usr/sbin/apachectl` (the Mac installed version), but running `apachectl -V` outputs the config info for the Homebrew installed version?  What is going on here when I run `apachectl start`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is direct from the whereis manual:

```
 The whereis utility checks the standard binary directories for the speci-
 fied programs, printing out the paths of any it finds.

 The path searched is the string returned by the sysctl(8) utility for the
 ``user.cs_path'' string.
```

The `user.cs_path` is the PATH set in the kernel.

```
sysctl user.cs_path
user.cs_path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

`which` will search the PATH set by your shell.

Comment: Thanks fd0.  So to confirm, "whereis" is showing me what my mac kernel has set for the apachectl executable paths, but the path that is actually being used on my shell will be the one shown by using "which"?  When running the "apachectl start" command, it will actually use the path shown when running "which"?  Is this correct?